# React native doesn't update automatically when changes are made

Tags: react-native, expo

The react native app doesn't update automatically when I make changes in files of a folder(even when I reload it) unless I restarted and run `yarn start` again. It only auto-updates the changes of any files in the same directory of the app.js
Can Anyone help me to figure out what can be the problem?
ps: I am using expo

Comment: On what device are you testing your app? Web, Android Device or Emulator?

Comment: Android, There's a typo so I edit it.

Comment: May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62732197/why-is-expo-not-refreshing-when-i-save-changes) helps you. 
In short shake your smartphone and tap on "Enable Fast Refresh".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it with:

rm -f ./.git/index.lock

Comment: Thank you, I found the solution in my case that I need to copy the project to WSL instead of accessing it from /mnt/..

Comment: why would you delete the git lock file?This way you would lost the git index

Comment: Sometimes, for whatever reason, a git process will not end gracefully. There are a number of reasons why this would happen. In this case, you can resolve the problem simply by removing the index.lock file manually via this command or a similar command on your operating system: rm .git/index.lock.
index.lock is not the same that index

Comment: Well unfortunately, it doesnt work here.